# Syntax Error (missinng operator) in Query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am attempting in Access to show some data in a listbox, but only data which meets a certain condition should be displayed, however my SQL is flagging the error;

`Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression  tblItem.[Status] WHERE (tblItem.[Status] = 'Unassigned`

Here is my full query

```
`SELECT tblItem.[Serial Number], 
        tblItem.[Item Description],
        tblItem.[Model], 
        tblItem.[Status] 
        WHERE (tblItem.[Status] = 'Unassigned') FROM tblItem;`
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the syntax for `select`:

`SELECT` ... `FROM` ... `WHERE` ... `ORDER BY`

Comment: Thanks, this was the sort of help i was after +1

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
SELECT tblItem.[Serial Number], 
    tblItem.[Item Description],
    tblItem.[Model], 
    tblItem.[Status] 
   FROM tblItem 
WHERE tblItem.[Status] = 'Unassigned'
```

I think You have misplaced the from and where clause